# How can i develop lRepository<TModel> in Manager class in Enttiy?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, entity-framework

i try to write manager class. But i can not use that :

```
return erpObj.Get(predicate);
```

How can i do that?

```
namespace Erp.BLL.Manager
{

    public interface ILoad
    {
        List<TResult> Load<TKey,TResult>(List<TKey> list, Func<TKey, TResult> select);
    }

    public interface IRepository<TModel>
    {
        List<TModel> Get(Func<TModel, bool> predicate);
    }

    public interface IErpManager
    {
       List<TResult> Load<TKey,TResult>(ILoad erpObj, List<TKey> list, Func<TKey, TResult> select);
       List<TModel> Get(IRepository<TModel> erpObj, Func<TModel, bool> predicate);
    }

    public class ErpManager : IErpManager
    {

        #region IErpManager Members

        public List<TResult> Load<TKey, TResult>(ILoad erpObj, List<TKey> list, Func<TKey, TResult> select)
        {
            return erpObj.Load(list, select);
        }

        public List<TModel> Get(IRepository<TModel> erpObj, Func<TModel, bool> predicate)
        {
            return erpObj.Get(predicate);
        }

        #endregion
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the template type to each Get() method:

```
    public interface IRepository<TModel>
    {
        List<TModel> Get<TModel>(Func<TModel, bool> predicate);
    }

    public interface IErpManager
    {
        List<TResult> Load<TKey, TResult>(ILoad erpObj, List<TKey> list, Func<TKey, TResult> select);
        List<TModel> Get<TModel>(IRepository<TModel> erpObj, Func<TModel, bool> predicate);
    }
```

ErpManager:

```
        public List<TModel> Get<TModel>(IRepository<TModel> erpObj, Func<TModel, bool> predicate)
        {
            return erpObj.Get(predicate);
        }
```

This will actually compile.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the implementation of `IRepository` or what you are using as DAL and you didn't even specify what problem you have, but usually in LINQ you use predicates like that:

```
Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> predicate
```

so

```
public interface IRepository<TModel>
{
    List<TModel> Get(Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> predicate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At a glance you need to specify the generic arg on the `Get` method on your `ErpManager`

```
public List<TModel> Get<TModel>(IRepository<TModel> erpObj, Func<TModel, bool> predicate)
    {
        return erpObj.Get(predicate);
    }
```

this also has to be reflected on your `IErpManager` interface.